# undefined method `each_child' for #<Dir:0x00007fcc34ccf6e8> Did you mean? each_slice

Tags: ruby, flutter, dart, cocoapods

Since I run `flutter upgrade` when I try to run my flutter app I get this error :

```
    [!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile
    undefined method `each_child' for #<Dir:0x00007fcc34ccf6e8>
    Did you mean?  each_slice

    /Users/youcefdahmani/Dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:54:in `block in flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/Dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:51:in `each'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/Dev/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:51:in `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/Work/Projects/MyShop/my_shop_app/ios/Podfile:39:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/Work/Projects/MyShop/my_shop_app/ios/Podfile:38:in `each'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/Work/Projects/MyShop/my_shop_app/ios/Podfile:38:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in `post_install!'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:897:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in
    `write!'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:299:in `generate_pods_project'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in `install!'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:899:in `rescue in run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:896:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:885:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:145:in `message'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:884:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in
    `write!'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:328:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `create_and_save_projects'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:299:in `generate_pods_project'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:178:in `integrate'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:166:in `install!'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /Users/youcefdahmani/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your
    Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

It seems to be an error linked to my ruby version but when I check my version It the 2.5.8. I try to search an answer to this issue but I found nothing. Please can you help to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your ruby version to at least 2.6.x

Flutter relies on ruby in the background, the each_child command was introduced in ruby since 2.6

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ThorstenC , I already did it and it works

Comment: I stumbled these days into the same problem.